# A styleguide for a web app's client-server communication

Tags: java, web-services, client-server, protocols

I want to use a Java app for business logic, database management, user authentication, and a JavaScript MVC app to handle all things UI. I am in need of a standardized and/or normalized communication styleguide or design pattern for my client/server communication.

The styleguide/pattern should be able to gracefully handle information pertaining to form fields, validation rules and errors, user profile information, and be extensible.  I know about SOAP and other such protocols... I need help with the structure/patterns/lexicon that I should be using for the the messages themselves.  So far I'm been defining the messages willy-nilly and it feels like I am reinventing the wheel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC architecture would do at application architecture level.
If you want desktop Java, use RMI it has a protocol and RMi server implemented.

Comment: Java RMI does seem like it could work well.  It would be nice if there was a standard communication pattern that was more platform/language agnostic in case I want to swap out Java for something else down the road or have the javascript app interface with another backend. But I guess even if there was a common pattern, some sort of conversion would need to happen to get from RMI to that...

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy Marionette - I think it has a great system of organization that Backbone kind of leaves up to you to create yourself. backbonerails.com gives a really, really good overview/tutorial (albeit the backend is in rails, but it's just a RESTful backend for the most part).

I feel that Backbone Marionnette gives you great controls over form fields and such, especially when you add in jQuery Validation (at least that's what I've always used for validation rules).